# how to shift text right in a tabular data

Tags: tables, spacing, text-decorations, text-manipulation

This is code in a simple document I am writing abbreviations.

```
\begin{tabular}{l l}  
        \textbf{VM} & Virtual Machine\\ 
        \textbf{AWS} & Amazon Web Services\\
        \textbf{GCP} & Google Cloud Platform \\
        \textbf{IaaS} & Infrastructure as a Service \\
        \textbf{PaaS} & Platform as a Service \\
        \textbf{SaaS} & Software as a Service \\
        \textbf{AaaS} & Authentication as a Service \\
        \textbf{CaaS} & Communication as a Service \\
        \textbf{EC2} & Proprietary Technology of Amazon,Stands for Elastic Compute Cloud \\
        \textbf{DaaS} & Desktop as a Service \\
        \textbf{Multi Tenant} & Multi tenant is a phrase used to describe multiple customers  using same cloud \\
        \textbf{Private Cloud} & Used to describe cloud implemented within corporate firewall.\\
        \textbf{Public Cloud} & Refers to cloud services provided to users over internet to any one who\\ purchases the service.\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

When I compile it then the last line

```
    \textbf{Public Cloud} & Refers to cloud services provided to users over internet to any one who\\ purchases the service.\\
```

this giving me problems I want to write more abbreviations but then it appears as following
[image: the last line below abbreviation]
in the image above I want to move the text
`purchases the service.` horizontally but I am not able to move it horizontally it comes below the bolded abbreviations and this makes my document ugly. What should I do in this case so that text shifts right and I can add more abbreviations.

Comment: Use `tabularx`: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}` and remove the `\\ ` between "who"  and "purchase".

Comment: delete the `\\ ` and change the second column from `l` to `p{5cm}` or whatever width you  want

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Are the abbreviations in your table sorted following a certain scheme? As a reader I would be happy if acronyms were sorted alphabetically. This does not seem to be the case in your table.

Comment: yes thanks for your comment I randomly made those. I did not had an idea it should be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @leandriis has already suggested in a comment, you may want to employ a `tabularx` environment, set its overall width to `\textwidth`, and use the `X` column type for the second, i.e., right-hand, column to allow automatic line wrapping while automatically selecting the maximum possible column width.

Another suggestion: Don't use **bold-face** for the first column, unless you either think it's essential to **shout** at your readers or just want to signal, "**Look at me, Mom! I know how to use bold-face in LaTeX!**" (and thus simply show no regard for the sentiment of your readers who don't really appreciate being shouted at). Even if one of these conditions is satisfied, don't encase every single word in the left-hand column of the table in `\textbf` wrappers; instead, just change the `l` column specifier to `>{\bfseries}l`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\begin{document}
\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}}  
VM   & Virtual Machine\\ 
AWS  & Amazon Web Services\\
GCP  & Google Cloud Platform \\
IaaS & Infrastructure as a Service \\
PaaS & Platform as a Service \\
SaaS & Software as a Service \\
AaaS & Authentication as a Service \\
CaaS & Communication as a Service \\
EC2  & Proprietary Technology of Amazon, Stands for Elastic Compute Cloud \\
DaaS & Desktop as a Service \\
Multi Tenant  & Multi tenant is a phrase used to describe multiple customers  using same cloud \\
Private Cloud & Used to describe cloud implemented within corporate firewall\\
Public Cloud  & Refers to cloud services provided to users over internet to any one who purchases the service\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed working example. It helped a lot and I was able to make a clear cut table as desired. Previously even though in above  comments it was mentioned use tabularx I was not able to understand , how to use it with just comment 1tabularx: \begin{tabularx}{\`. Your detailed working example helped me understand my errors and the clear cut syntax to write.

Comment: @koeradoera - Many thanks for letting me know that my answer was useful. And, kudos for not taking my little rant about using **bold-face** personally. :-)

Comment: I want to know what is meant by @{} and what is the next symbol you used is it L or 1 and what is meant by X in the content inside `textwidth{}`,

Comment: @koeradoera - The `@{}` particles serve to eliminate the whitespace padding that would otherwise be inserted by default at the left-hand and right-hand edges of the table. The basic column types recognized by LaTeX are `l` (left), `c` (center), `r` (right), and `p{<width>}` (paragraph with width `<width>`.). `X` is a column type provided by the `tabularx` package. The `X` column type is, essentially, the same as the `p` column type, *except* that LaTeX calculates its width automatically, as a residual. Hence, `X` -- unlike `p` -- does not take a width specifier argument.